# Relu function, return 0 and big numbers

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning

Hi I'm new in neuralNetworks with tensorflow. I've taken a small fraction of the spaces365 dataset. I want to make a neural network to classify betweeen 10 places.

For that I've tried to do a small copy of a vgg network. The problem I have is that at the output of the softmax function I get a one-hot encoded array. Looking for problems in my code, I've realised that the output of relu functions are either 0 or a big number (around 10000).

I don't know where I'm wrong. Here it's my code:

```
def variables(shape):
    return tf.Variable(2*tf.random_uniform(shape,seed=1)-1)

def layerConv(x,filter):
    return tf.nn.conv2d(x,filter, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME') 
def maxpool(x):
    return tf.nn.max_pool(x,[1,2,2,1],[1,2,2,1],padding='SAME')

weights0 = variables([3,3,1,16])

l0 = tf.nn.relu(layerConv(input,weights0))
l0 = maxpool(l0)

weights1 = variables([3,3,16,32])
l1 = tf.nn.relu(layerConv(l0,weights1))
l1 = maxpool(l1)

weights2 = variables([3,3,32,64])
l2 = tf.nn.relu(layerConv(l1,weights2))
l2 = maxpool(l2)

l3 = tf.reshape(l2,[-1,64*32*32])

syn0 = variables([64*32*32,1024])
bias0 =  variables([1024])
l4 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(l3,syn0) + bias0)
l4 = tf.layers.dropout(inputs=l4, rate=0.4)

syn1 = variables([1024,10])
bias1 = variables([10])
output_pred = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(l4,syn1) + bias1)

error = tf.square(tf.subtract(output_pred,output),name='error')
loss = tf.reduce_sum(error, name='cost')

#TRAINING

optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate)
train = optimizer.minimize(loss)
```

The input of the neural netWork is a normalized grayscale image of 256*256 pixels.
The learning Rate is 0.1 and the Batch Size is 32.

Thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essentially what reLu is :

```
def relu(vector):
    vector[vector < 0] = 0
    return vector
```

and softmax:

```
def softmax(x):
    e_x = np.exp(x - np.max(x))
    return e_x / e_x.sum(axis=0)
```

The output of softmax being a one-hot encoded array means there is a problem and that could be many things.

You can try reducing the learning_rate for starters, you can use `1e-4` / `1e-3` and check. If it doesn't work, try adding some regularization. I am also skeptical about your weight initialization.

Regulatization : This is a form of regression, that constrains/ regularizes or shrinks the coefficient estimates towards zero. In other words, this technique discourages learning a more complex or flexible model, so as to avoid the risk of overfitting. - [Regularization in ML](https://towardsdatascience.com/regularization-in-machine-learning-76441ddcf99a)

Link to : [Build a multilayer neural network with L2 regularization in tensorflow](https://markojerkic.com/build-a-multi-layer-neural-network-with-l2-regularization-with-tensorflow/)

Comment: Thank you for your quick anser! I've tried to change the learning rate but still doesn't work. I don't understand how regularization works, could yo explain that? What happen with my weigth initialization? What I try to do there, is initialize a variable with 0 mean and std equals to 1.

Comment: @Mik3l I have updated my answer, Please follow two of those links.

Comment: That's true! my problem was the initialization. I took the example from MNIST for experts provided by tensorFlow and I solved my problem. Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 1):

The problem you have is your weight initialization. NN are highly complicated non-convex optimization problems. Therefore, a good init is paramount to getting any good results. If you use ReLUs you should use the Initialization proposed by He et al. (https://www.cv-foundation.org/openaccess/content_iccv_2015/papers/He_Delving_Deep_into_ICCV_2015_paper.pdf?spm=5176.100239.blogcont55892.28.pm8zm1&file=He_Delving_Deep_into_ICCV_2015_paper.pdf).

In Essence the initialization of your network should be initialized with iid gaussian distributed values with mean 0 and standard deviation as follows:

```
stddev = sqrt(2 / Nr_input_neurons)
```

Comment: That's true! my problem was the initialization. I took the example from MNIST for experts provided by tensorFlow and I solved my problem. Thank you very much!!